# How to set up an SSD as a cache for the big Hard Drive?

Tags: linux

I want to order
https://www.fdcservers.net/order-1-w.php?plan_id=538

According to http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2013/04/linux-3-9-brings-ssd-caching-and-drivers-to-support-modern-pcs/ linux have built in capability to allow using SSD to cache hard drive.

How to do so?

Where is the tutorial?

This feature is already in the standard kernel right? WOuld it work on centosh?

Can I just upgrade existing kernel?

Answer (score 6):

Check out [bcache](http://bcache.evilpiepirate.org/), which is [integrated into the mainline kernel from 3.10](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTM2ODM), but which should also work with older kernels with a bit of effort -- you'll have to compile your own, using the patches provided.  (It's not as scary as it sounds!)

There is also a minimal comparison of dm-cache and bcache [here](https://lwn.net/Articles/548348/).

Comment: Okay, this is 11/6 now. 3 months have passed. Which one is right? Dm-cache or bcache? Which one is integrated into the mainline kernel? If it's integrated why do I have to patch?

Comment: you have to patch due to your kernel version. centos is on 2.6 while the main version now is 3.x. you can check the change log of centos kernel and verify if they added the solutions provided or if you have to patch your kernel.

Answer (score 2):

A little of google search based on your initial link, led to this.

[SSD Caching Using dm-cache Tutorial](http://blog.kylemanna.com/linux/2013/06/30/ssd-caching-using-dmcache-tutorial/)

Answering the kernel update, from what I see the latest version has kernel 2.6.32-358. So the kernel will not have this feature in it. [Cent OS version and Kernel versions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS)

You can try and patch the device-mapper [check here](http://www.sourceware.org/dm/patches.html) and also install the dm-cache (includes patching of the kernel, I did not did into it so not sure if it will work with 2.6 )[check here](https://github.com/mingzhao/dm-cache)

Comment: latest version of what? Of centosh kernel?

Comment: yes, I just updated with the link that has CentOS and Kernel versions